# When using externs and targeting JavaScript, how do I force the Haxe compiler to use require statements?

Tags: javascript, haxe

I'm using some externs from [haxe-js-kit](https://github.com/clemos/haxe-js-kit), and I'm targeting client-side JS. As per the `haxe-js-kit` instructions, I included the following line in my `build.hxml` file:

```
--macro npm.Package.export("package.json")
```

Now when I compile, a `package.json` file is generated which identifies the dependencies I need to install. So then I run:

```
npm install
```

And those dependencies are installed in `node_modules/`. Now I'd like to package the built JS for my app (generated by the Haxe compiler) with the JS libraries I just downloaded into `node_modules/`. Usually, I'd use something like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to do this, but webpack depends on there being CommonJS or AMD dependency declarations. The Haxe compiler does not insert `require` statements in the compiled JS--it  assumes that those dependencies will be globally available.

Haxe *does* provide a mechanism for putting CommonJS `require` statements in the compiled JS: [`@:jsRequire("fs")`](http://haxe.org/manual/target-javascript-require.html). But the author of the extern is responsible for adding this annotation to their extern classes, and [it doesn't look](https://github.com/clemos/haxe-js-kit/blob/develop/js/npm/socketio/Socket.hx) like `haxe-js-kit` does this .

As a client of externs, is there a way to tell the Haxe compiler to include `require` statements in the output JS, so I can use a tool like webpack to package up my dependencies into a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps add the metadata yourself with a compiler argument:

```
--macro addMetadata('@:jsRequire("fs")', 'path.to.TheExtern')
```

Thus, even if you don't own to source, you can decorate the class with Haxe metadata.

Alternately, you could file an issue on the [haxe-js-kit repo](https://github.com/clemos/haxe-js-kit/issues) asking why it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks—and issue has been filed.